# Removing items from a list - algorithm time complexity

Tags: algorithm, big-o

Problem consists of two sorted lists with no duplicates of sizes n and m. First list contains strings that should be deleted from second list.

Simplest algorithm would have to do `nxm` operations (I believe that terminology for this is "quadratic time"?).

Improved solution would be to take advantage of the fact that both list are sorted and skip strings with index that is lower than last deleted index in future comparisons. 
I wonder what time complexity would that be?

Are there any solutions for this problem with better time complexity?

Comment: Please change your title into something more useful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should look into [Merge sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort). This is the basic idea behind why it works efficiently.

The idea is to scan the two lists together, which takes `O(n+m)` time:

Make a pointer `x` for first list, say `A` and another pointer `y` for the second list, say `B`. Set `x=0` and `y=0`. While `x < n` and `y < m`, if `A[x] < B[y]`, then add `A[x]` to the new merged list and increment `x`. Otherwise add `B[y]` to the new list and increment `y`. Once you hit `x=n` or `y=m`, take on the remaining elements from `B` or `A`, respectively.

Answer (score 5):

I believe the complexity would be `O(n+m)`, because every item in each of the lists would be visited exactly once.

Answer (score 0):

A counting/bucket sort algorithm would work where each string in the second list is a bucket.

You go through the second list (takes m time) and create your buckets. You then go through your first list (takes n time) and increment the number of occurances. You then would have to go through each bucket (takes m time) again and only return strings that occur once. A Trie or a HashMap would work well for storing a buckets. Should be O(n+m+m). If you use a HashSet, in the second pass instead of incrementing a counter, you remove from the Set. It should be O(n+m+(m-n)).

Answer (score -1):

Might it be O(m + log(n)) if binary search is used?

Comment: There is no searching required.